# How to select all checkboxes with a class name inside a table by table id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have several tables on my page, and a table with the id of workOneTable. I have several rows in the table with class name of .rsvLine and more with class name .vtoLine. I need to be able to select all checkboxes in workOneTable with class name .rsvLine.
I have tried several things.

```
$( '#workOneTable :checkbox.rsvLine' ).prop( 'checked', this.checked );

$( '#workOneTable' ).find( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).prop( 'checked', true );

$( '#workOneTable tbody .rsvLine :checkbox' ).prop( 'checked' );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Here is the most relevant part of the html code.

```
<table id=workOneTable>
<thead>
    several rows here
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
        <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I can select the right ones if I do not use the table id. It will select the .rsvLine in all tables. this is the code I used for that.

```
$( '.rsvLine :checkbox' ).each( function ()
            {
                if ( !$( this ).prop( "checked" ) )
                {
                    this.click();
                }
            } );
```

Comment: share your html code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Manish I added some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this

```
$( "#workOneTable .rsvLine input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Here is an example

```js
$( "#workOneTable .rsvLine input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=workOneTable>
<thead>
    several rows here
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox" ></td>
        <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
        <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</div>
```

Comment: one more question. I am using Angular and when I select all those check boxes I get a $apply already in progress error.

Comment: I dont use Angular so cant help at that...Post another question someone else may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set `.checked` property to opposite of current `Boolean` value of `.checked` property use `!` operator preceding `this.checked` at `.prop()` value

```js
$(function() {
  $('#workOneTable .rsvLine :checkbox')
  .each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', !this.checked)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="workOneTable">
  <thead>
    several rows here
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="rsvLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="vtoLine"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
      <td class="rsvLine">other stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the "each" method. This is enough:

```
$("#workOneTable td.rsvLine :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```